# Sort specific values from a column in panda data frame

Tags: pandas

i have a data frame, for example :

```
df =     ID  aa_len                                             aa_seq  \
0  001      45  [M, R, S, R, Y, P, L, L, R, G, E, A, V, A, V, ...   
1  002      45  [M, R, S, R, Y, P, L, L, R, G, E, A, V, A, V, ...   

   mut_position  
0              [-1]  
1  [5, 94, 95, 132]
```

The "mut_position" can be -1 or other non negative number (2,3,4) or a list of few numbers.
for example it can be -1 as in 001. a list of a few like in 002 or one number- for example 4.
i need to count the number of subjects who doesnt have -1.

i tried to so that by comparing to -1 and collect the ones that r different but it dosent seems to work...

```
def count_mutations(df, ref_aa_len):
nomis = -1
mutation = (df['mut_position']) != nomis 
print (mutation)
```

what i get it True for both (ignore the ref_aa_len, that should come later)-

```
0    True
1    True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need `list compehension` with generator and sum of boolean `True`s:

```
df['non_negative'] = [sum(y != -1 for y in x) for x in df['mut_position']]
print (df)
       mut_position  non_negative
0              [-1]             0
1  [5, 94, 95, 132]             4
```

If possible scalars also:

```
print (df)
    mut_position
0           [-1]
1  [5,94,95,132]
2              6
3             -1

df['non_negative'] = [sum(y != -1 for y in x)  
                     if isinstance(x, list) 
                     else int(x != -1) for x in df['mut_position']]
print (df)
       mut_position  non_negative
0              [-1]             0
1  [5, 94, 95, 132]             4
2                 6             1
3                -1             0
```

---

If need check first values if list for `-1` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mut_position':[[-1], [5,94,95,132],[2,-1], [-1]]})

print (df)
       mut_position
0              [-1]
1  [5, 94, 95, 132]
2           [2, -1]
3              [-1]

df1 = df[df['mut_position'].str[0] != -1 ]
print (df1)
       mut_position
1  [5, 94, 95, 132]
2           [2, -1]
```

**Detail**:

`str[0]` working for select first char of string or first value of iterable:

```
 print (df['mut_position'].str[0])
0   -1
1    5
2    2
3   -1
Name: mut_position, dtype: int64
```

And for check `-1` for any position use `all`:

```
df1 = df[[all(y != -1 for y in x) for x in df['mut_position']]]
print (df1)
       mut_position
1  [5, 94, 95, 132]
```

List comprehension return boolena list:

```
print ([all(y != -1 for y in x) for x in df['mut_position']])
[False, True, False, False]
```

Comment: I just solved it a minute after uploading the question :)

just added [0] to the mut_position. The small details.... But thanks!

Comment: @TalyaShacham - Yes, please check last edited answer with sample data.

Comment: Yeah it works.
I dont really understand it so i will stare at it for a while... Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, I try explain more.